# How to receive SUPL RESPONSE from supl.google.com for LPP protocol?

Tags: gps, location, supl-2.0

I am implementing a client with `SUPL 2.0`.

I have prepared a `SUPL START` message with `LPP` protocol information. 
If I send this message to `supl.google.com`, server replies with `SUPL END` with statuscode error posProtocolMismatch.

But `SUPL START` message with `RRLP` protocol is received by google server and it replies with `SUPL RESPONSE`.

I read from internet that `supl.google.com` does support `LPP` and `SUPL2.0`. I'm using port number 7275. Positioning technology is `SETBased`.

Does anyone knows how to receive `SUPL RESPONSE` from `supl.google.com` for `LPP` protocol?

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply, but I believe `supl.google.com` does support LPP now. Check out [this implementation](https://github.com/google/supl-client) of a SUPL client by Google.